# SPARQL date conversion

Tags: date, sparql, dotnetrdf

We have created a SPARQL endpoint using `dotnetrdf` and I am a beginner when related to SPARQL. The date fields have been stored as strings in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`. Now, there is requirement for date comparison (`> <`) for which the string will have to be converted to `xsd:datetime` or `xsd:date` in the SPARQL query. Is there a way to do this? Any other alternative?

Are there any good examples available for date related SPARQL queries in `dotnetrdf`?

Thanks.

Comment: dotNetRDF supports date based SPARQL queries according to the SPARQL specs so your data must be in `xsd:dateTime` or `xsd:date` formats for this to work

Comment: I added the datetime as a string literal as string since could not find the method for adding datetime.

Comment: The code used for adding is as below                     ILiteralNode Datelit = g.CreateLiteralNode(SampleDateValue);
IUriNode DateUri = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create(http://url/sampledate"));
g.Assert(new Triple(dotNetRDF, DateUri, Datelit));                                            What is the method for adding the data in xsd:datetime format? Please suggest..

Comment: There is an extension method `ToLiteral()` that can be applied to most simple types (int, long, byte, DateTime, TimeSpan etc) which will generate a literal with appropriate lexical value and datatype

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is that you *can*, but probably don't want to!

You should be able to do it with the SPARQL 1.1 [`SUBSTR` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-substr), along with `concat` and `strdt`.

Something along the lines of

```
strdt(concat(substr(?x, 7, 4), '-', substr(?x, 1, 2), '-', substr(?x, 4, 2), 'T00:00:00'), xsd:dateTime)
```

Where `?x` is bound to your `MM/DD/YYYY` date value. The return value of that function should be a legal `xsd:dateTime`, assuming no typos.

If it were me, I'd extract all the `MM/DD/YYYY` data, process it externally, and add additional data as `xsd:dates` or `xsd:dateTimes`.